# Auto Scroll To Top Of Page Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, blackberry

How can I auto scroll to the bottom of the browser window when a page is loaded, which in turn will push the address bar up?

Comment: "Auto Scroll To Top ..." ~ "How can I auto scroll to the bottom ..." - - - I call shenanigans!!!

Comment: try [this example](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/)
.Also which version of blackberry,you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your page is longer than the iOS devices' screen height the script below will work and hide the address bar at the top of the safari app, if that's what you're trying to achieve...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

If the page is not longer than the viewport height there is nowhere to scroll to and this script wont work!

However if the website is added to the homescreen of an iOS device the following line will hide all interface components

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

You can read about this in the apple documentation: [Apple Dev Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/configuringwebapplications/configuringwebapplications.html)

Comment: I am targeting blackberry not iphone unfortunatly

Comment: oh, sorry, you may want to write that into the question, I can't help there, sorry :)